# Solving boundary value problem, put up linear equation system

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

For $\Omega = (0,1)^2 \subseteq \mathbb R^2, f \in C(\Omega)$ consider the boundary value problem:

$-\Delta u(x,y) + u(x,y) = f(x,y)~ \forall (x,y) \in \Omega \\u(0,y) = u(1,y)~ \forall y \in (0,1) \\ u(x,0) = u(x,1)~ \forall x \in (0,1)$

For discretization let be: $n \in \mathbb N,~ h= \frac{1}{n}, ~ x_i =(i-1) \cdot h, ~ y_j = (j-1) \cdot h, ~ i,j = 1, \ldots, n+1.$

I want to find the linear equation system for the discretized solution: $u_{i,j} = u(x_i,y_j), ~i,j= 1, \ldots, n$.

So I need to find $Au = b$, where $b$ is given by $f_{i,j} = f(x_i,y_j)$.

I found out that

$\begin{align}
\Delta u_{i,j}=\frac{1}{h^2} [u_{i-1,j}+u_{i+1,j}-4u_{ij}
+u_{i,j-1}+u_{i,j+1}]
\end{align}$,

but now I'm struggeling how to put that in an equation system with regard to the boundary conditions. Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need help with setting up the linear system of equations, or just adding the boundary conditions into the system?

Comment: I would be glad for help for both!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to rearrange the unknowns, $u_{i,j}$. They are points on a square lattice. Conventionally, we go from the lower left corner, to the right, then go back to the left, but one unit upward, and repeat this process. This way, you will get $(n+1)^2$ unknowns, named as $u_i, i=1,...,(n+1)^2$.

When setting up the equations, you have to be careful about the correspondence between your $u_{i,j}$ and $u_i$.

For example, let $n=5$, then $u_{3,4}$ is corresponding to $u_{21}$. This gives one of the equations: 
$$- \frac{1}{h^2} [u_{2,4}+u_{4,4}-4 u_{3,4}+u_{3,3}+u_{3,5}]+u_{3,4}=f_{3,4}$$ 
which is equivalent to (by some counting)
$$- \frac{1}{h^2} [u_{20}+u_{22}-4 u_{21}+u_{15}+u_{27}]+u_{21}=f_{21}$$
Do this for all $i,j$, you will get a $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ system, with, for example, diagonal elements $\frac{4}{h^2}+1$.

For the boundary conditions, $u(0,y)$ can be represented by $u_1, u_7, ...$. $u(1,y)$ can be represented by $u_6, u_12,...$ To incorporate that boundary condition, change equation $1,7,...$ to $u_1-u_6=0, u_7-u_12=0,...$. The other one can be done similarly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot so far. I am a bit confused about the change of indices. I thought for $Au =b$, where $u=(u_{1,1}, \ldots, u_{1,n}, u_{2,1}, \ldots, u_{2,n}, \ldots, \ldots, u_{n,1}, \ldots, u_{n,n})^t$ the i-th row of $A$ looks like $\frac{1}{h^2}[0, \ldots, 0, -1,0, \ldots,0,-1,4,-1,0, \ldots,0,-1,0, \ldots, 0] + [0,\ldots, 0,1,0, \ldots, 0]$, $dim A = n^2 \times n^2.$ But how to put the boundary conditions $u(0,y) = u(1,y), u(x,0)=u(x,1)$ in there? (I'm sorry, here I'm also confused with your illustration). Or is this wrong?

Comment: Come to think of it, the problem does not have a unique solution. What does the problem ask for? Your matrix is correct, I just used $u_1, ... u_{(n+1)^2}$ instead of yours. Now for the boundary conditions, if we ignore the 4 corner points, there are $4(n-1)$ boundary points. Each interior point has an equation corresponding with it. But there are only $2(n-1)$ equations for the $4(n-1)$ boundary points, which are, for example $u_{2,1}-u_{2,n+1}=0, ...$.

Comment: I understand the needed equations, but I still do not how know how to put them into the system $Au = b$ as the entry $u_{2,n+1}$ is not part of $u$, or is it $u_{2,1} - u_{2,n} = 0$, sorry if this is stupid..